# Как правильно понедельно агрегировать массивы дней в JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, дата, momentjs, агрегация

Для примера возьмём временной диапазон от `10.05.2019` до `25.05.2019`.

Даты на этом интервале нужно агрегировать вот так (для краткости `2019` опустим):

```
const result = [
  [                                    '05-10', '05-11', '05-12'], // неделя 1
  ['05-13', '05-14', '05-15', '05-16', '05-17', '05-18', '05-19'], // неделя 2
  ['05-20', '05-21', '05-22', '05-23', '05-24', '05-25'         ], // неделя 3
];
```

Как лучше решить эту задачу средствами JS?
Возможно ли это реализовать, произвольно меняя первый день недели?
Помогут ли в этом библиотеки [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) и её расширение [`moment-range`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range)?

Comment: @Дмытрык Я привёл переменную с многомерным массовом как результат, который я ожидаю на выходе.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666564/how-to-aggregate-arrays-of-days-weekly-in-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример
Только для одного месяца, но дописать не сложно

```js
function getArrWeek(startDay, month/*-1*/, year, endDay) {
    let s = new Date(year, month - 1, startDay)
    let d = s.getDate() - 1 // для цикла
    let w = s.getDay() - 1 // для массива
    let e = endDay > 0 ? endDay : (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate()
    let arr = [[]]
    let i = arr[0]
    while (d++ < e) {
        if (w > 6) {
            i = arr[(arr.push([]) - 1)]
            w = 0
        }
        i[w++] = (s.setDate(d), s.toDateString())
    }
    return arr
}

// !!! ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ОДНОГО МЕСЯЦА, ИНАЧЕ ПИСАТЬ ФУНКЦИЮ ПАРСИНГА МЕСЯЦЕВ И ЛЕТ
const startDateString = '2019.11.2'
const endDateString = '2019.11.12'
const s = new Date(startDateString)
const e = new Date(endDateString)

console.log(JSON.stringify(getArrWeek(
    s.getDate(),
    s.getMonth() + 1,
    s.getFullYear(),
    e.getDate()
), null, 2))

//
// можно руками
console.log(JSON.stringify(getArrWeek(24, 12, 2019), null, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильн понял то фильтр по такому условию: `!!startDate && !!endDate && dayInArray > startDate && dayInArray < endDate`